# Using HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync to WebApi Rest service fails to deliver complex type (Monotouch/iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, complextype

I can not solve this after searching the web and trying many different solutions. After 3 days I am seeking wisdom and experience of the SO collective.

I have a WebApi in Visual Studio 2013. The interface for one method is:

```
public Product[] SearchProducts([FromBody]DistanceBasedSearchArgs args) 
{
      ...

}
```

The parameter is a complex type (a class). There is a base SearchArgs class and a descendent class with additional search details:

```
public class SearchArgs
{
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}

public class DistanceBasedSearchArgs : SearchArgs
{
    public int MaxDistance { get; set;}
}
```

I have tested this setup on Windows within Visual Studio 2013. I have written unit tests to call this API using HttpClient and modified it to post by HTML page. All of it works perfectly.

I thought it would be a cinch now to copy over that code into Xamarin Studio 3 to allow my iOS application to make calls to the WebApi. Here is the code:

```
public static async Task<ProductSearchResult[]> SearchProducts(DistanceBasedSearchArgs args) 
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient (new NativeMessageHandler (true))) 
{
       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync ("http:///thehost.com:1234", args);
   return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ProductSearchResult[]>().Result;
}
```

The problem is that when the WebApi method is called, the complex type DistanceBasedSearchArgs is not properly deserialized on the server side. All the values to are default values (i.e. MaxDistance is always 0 even though on the client side, it has a value of 25.

I have used CharlesProxy on the Max/iOS side to capture the requeset. The request appears to be posting the correct JSON. Here is what CharlesProxy captures:

```
URL                 http://thehost.com:1234/api/Product/SearchProducts/
Status          Complete
Response Code   200 OK
Protocol            HTTP/1.1
Method          POST
Kept Alive          No
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Client Address  /127.0.0.1
Remote Address  thehost.com/thehost.com (ips replaced)
```

The JSON text under the "Request" tab as captured by JSON:

```
{
    "MaxDistance": 25,
    "Keyword": "Sushi",
    "Page": 1,
    "PageSize": 25
}
```

However, the arguments I pass in to the method is not deserialized properly. This is a problem ONLY when making the call from the iOS app and using Post..Async methods. I simply get a class with default values. As mentioned previously, it works perfectly fine on Windows unit tests using HttpClient. Here are the things I have tried:

1) Using HTTP get which passes in the parameters just fine.

2) Used query string which also passes in params fine.

3) Tried RestSharp with Method.Post and that worked fine passing in the args (the args had proper values on the server side).

4)  I have tried the HTTPClient from System.Net, from Nuget Packages HttpClient (v2.2.22) and WebApi Client (v5.1.2), ModernHttpClient.

I just can't figure out why calling PostAsJasonAsync won't properly pass the JSON in the body to be used as the argument for the webapi call. Can anyone tell me what I am not doing right?

Comment: I would love to be able to get this far.  For Xamarin iOS the HttpClient does not include the methods like postasjsonasyc, and only includes postasync.